# I don't understand this max function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I am new to programming and python. I was playing around with this max function and I don't understand why it is not returning the maximum value when actually it should

```
n = [11,3,9]
first_last = [n[1],n[-1]]
largest = max(first_last)
print(largest)
```

The result is 9 instead of 11 but why?

Comment: n[1] = 3, n[-1] = 9, obivously 9 is bigger.  try n[0] and n[-1]

Comment: you probably want to set: `first_last = [n[0],n[-1]]`

Comment: Question: why do you think that taking the max between first and last item in an array - will give you the max over the entire array? what if the array was [1,2,3,4,3,2,1] ?

Comment: because `first_last = [n[1],n[-1]]` is giving you `[3,9]`.  do what alfasin suggested.

Comment: what you don't understand is how indexing is done in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing in python starts from 0. 
So do

```
list = [11,3,9]
print(max(list[0],list[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

`n = [11,3,9]
first_last = [n[1],n[-1]]
largest = max(first_last)
print(largest)`

Indexing in python starts from 0. While negative sequence indices (-1, -2, -3,.....) helps in accessing array from the last element.

So, your n[1]=3 and n[-1]=9. This makes first_last = [3, 9]. So when you passed first_last in the max function, it gave you the maximum value among the elements of first_last which is 9.